# StandardSetController and Too many Locator Rows

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I'm creating a Search page so user can search all of the objects by Super Customers and I have ran into a snag.  Originally I set up my search like this .

Edit -- I Don't want to Pagination that many records, It looks like on load the entire Oppty Object is getting queried THEN once the Search is done it filters it.

```
    public List<Case> setOppCon (Set<Id> accountIds){
        return[
        SELECT Name,OwnerId,StageName,RecordTypeId,Design_Region__c,Design_Territory__c,Potential_Value1__c,
                            LastModifiedDate,Probability 
                         FROM Opportunity WHERE Account__c IN: accountIds];
    }
```

I was not thinking of pagination when I built it , so in order to allow pagination I switched it so I can now use StandSetControllers as such

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setOppCon {
    get {
        if(setOppCon == null) {
            setOppCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Name,OwnerId,StageName,RecordTypeId,Design_Region__c,Design_Territory__c,Potential_Value1__c,
                            LastModifiedDate,Probability 
                         FROM Opportunity]));
        }
        return setOppCon;
    }
    set;
}      
     public List<Opportunity> getOpps(Set<Id> accountIds) {
             setOppCon.setPageSize(5);
            return (List<Opportunity>) setOppCon.getRecords();
     }
```

But now the issue that I am having is that I am getting an error `Too many query locator rows: 10001`, and I believe that is happening because  now I am querying every single record at load and filtering rather than querying with the filter in place.

Pagination I thought was suppose to fix that, but I am having no luck.  I'm somewhat confident I did the class correct, I am unsure about the VF Page.

```
</apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunities">
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!optyList}" var="opty">
    <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Name"><apex:outputLink value="/{!opty.Id}">{!opty.Name}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.OwnerId}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.StageName}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.RecordTypeId}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.Design_Region__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.Design_Territory__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.Potential_Value1__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.LastModifiedDate}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.Probability}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!opty.StageName}"/>                  
    </apex:pageblockTable>
         <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setOppCon.hasPrevious}" value="First" action="{!setOppCon.first}"/>
          <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setOppCon.hasPrevious}" value="Previous" action="{!setOppCon.previous}"/>
          <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setOppCon.pageNumber * setOppCon.pageSize) < setOppCon.ResultSize}" value="{!setOppCon.pageNumber * setOppCon.pageSize} Of {!setOppCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
          <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setOppCon.pageNumber * setOppCon.pageSize) >= setOppCon.ResultSize}" value="{!setOppCon.ResultSize} Of {!setOppCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>            
          <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setOppCon.hasNext}" value="Next" action="{!setOppCon.next}"/>            
          <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setOppCon.hasNext}" value="Last" action="{!setOppCon.last}"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Seems like pagination only works for up to 10k records based on Peter's response here:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42702/how-to-paginate-10000-records-soql-offset-and-standardsetcontroller-too-limit

Comment: @Scott I just don't know where to start if I were to filter there, my search is looking through 5 different objects.

Comment: @Scott and to Add onto your comment, I don't want to pagination that many records